# unsubscribe from combineLatest

Tags: rxjs

I have the following code snippet. I'm not sure how to clean up all subscriptions or if I made any mistakes. Please help to improve it.

I'm using it within an Angular service to initialize my application.

```
  destroy$ = new Subject();

  loadData() : void {
    const loadData1 = this.store.select(selector); // first sets loading to true, then to false
    const loadData2 = this.store.select(selector); // first sets loading to true, then to false
    const loadData3 = this.store.select(selector); // first sets loading to true, then to false

    combineLatest([loadData1, loadData2, loadData3])
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
      .subscribe(data => {
        const a = data[0];
        const b = data[1];
        const c = data[2];

          ...

         if (a.loadedSuccessfully && b.loadedSuccessfully && c.loadedSuccessfully) {
            ...
            // do something with the data
            ...
            // clean up
            this.destroy$.next(true);
            this.destroy$.complete();
          }
        }
      });
  }
```

**Questions:**

(1) Did I make any mistakes?

(2) How can I improve it?

(3) What about the Observables loadData1-3. There is no subscription in the beginning. So the following line does not create a memory leak, right?

```
*const loadData1 = this.store.select(selector);*
```

Does combineLatest create the subscriptions for loadData1-3 and unsbscribe it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[first](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/first) operators : Emits only the first value (or the first value that meets some condition.

If you want to do something on `loadData1-3` all `loadedSuccessfully`.

try this

```js
loadData(): void {
  const loadData1 = this.store.select(selector);
  const loadData2 = this.store.select(selector);
  const loadData3 = this.store.select(selector);
  
  combineLatest([loadData1, loadData2, loadData3]).pipe(
    first((arr) => arr.every(({loadedSuccessfully}) => loadedSuccessfully))
  ).subscribe(/* do something with the data */);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> (1) Did I make any mistakes?

Your solution will work, but it will work only once, because you can't complete `destroy$` twice. Usually an `Subject` called `destroy$` is invoked and completed once, when the component or service is destroyed, e.g. in `ngOnDestroy`.

I believe you chose the wrong operator here. If you want exaclty one emission, you should prefer `forkJoin` over `combineLatest`, it will also make `destroy$` superflous, since it emits only once or never.

> (2) How can I improve it?

Except for changing the operator I'd suggest to expand tuples in the parameter declartion, e.g.

```
.subscribe(data => {
    const a = data[0];
    const b = data[1];
    const c = data[2];
```

could become  `.subscribe(([a, b, c]) => {`

It's also a bit odd, that the result has a boolean that indicates wether or not loading was successfull. I believe the idiomatic way would be to use the operators `catchError` and `throwError` for error handling.

> (3) What about the Observables loadData1-3. There is no subscription in the beginning. So the following line does not create a memory leak, right?
>
> [...]
>
> Does combineLatest create the subscriptions for loadData1-3 and unsbscribe it?

Exactly! When you subscribe to a piped `Observable` it will automatically subscribe to all the Observables it depends on and when you unsubscribe from it, it will also unsubscribe from all of it's dependencies.